# removed item from collection still valid?

Tags: c#, collections, observablecollection

When I remove items from a collection, what's happening from the .net side ?
Is a reference to the remove item still valid ?

```
class myObject
{
    int i = 1;
}
...
public ObservableCollection<myObject> myObjects = new ObservableCollection<myObject>();
...
myObjects.Add(new myObject());
myObjects.Add(new myObject());

myObject removedItem = myObjects[1];
myObjects.RemoveAt(1);

// removedItem still valid ?
```

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just try ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant In languages such as C or C++, "just trying" wouldn't do the work. Freed memory may still be accessible by accident.

Comment: I agree with you. But in this case, the question is the opposite : is the removed item still accessible ? A try is enough to find out that yes, it is.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Theoretically it might be accessible while testing but then break in production. That's why "just trying" is a bad advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it won't be taken by Garbage Collection, because it is still referenced by another variable in your application.

Comment: ok. I noticed The visual studio debugger has problems in evaluating such objects. It says: removedItem.i threw an Exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in C#, as long as you hold a reference to an object, the object is there and the Garbage Collector won't free its memory. `removedItem` is a reference to the object. So yes, you can use the object referenced by `removedItem` without problems.

Answer (score 1):

`myObject` is a reference type so the collection only conatains a **reference** to the actual object.

When you do `myObject removedItem = myObjects[1];` you now have 2 references to 1 object.

Removing an item from the collection only removes the reference from the collection and not the object. This is an important concept.

So when you do `myObjects.RemoveAt(1);` you are down to 1 reference to 1 object. Importantly, the object still has the variable `removedItem` referencing it

The Garbage Collector will not try to free up the memory while there are references to the object.

Once `removedItem` is assigned a different value, null, or it goes out of scope `myObject` will have no references (assuming you haven't created anymore) and be marked for Garbage Collection and it will no longer be valid.

However, in reality, it may stay in memory longer because the Garbage Collector guarantees the memory will be freed, but not *when* it will be freed. (This last part is probably not important for your puposes, but worth mentioning all the same.)